# Why can the total connected load be equal to system capacity ? what does "maximum demand of the entire system" really mean?

Tags: power, ac, power-engineering

I read some factor in the power transmission ,and there are something i don't really understand

**Question 1**

demand factor \$ = \frac{maximum \ demand}{total  \ connected \  load }=\frac{maximum \ demand}{system \ capacity }\$,why can the total  connected   load \$\$= system capacity?

Because i think the total load means how much power does my total load consume,and system capacity means how much maximum power can the system provide to the load ,they should be different,why can them be equal?

**Question 2**

Diversity factor  \$ = \frac{sum \   individual  \  maximum  \  demands}{ maximum  \  demand  \ of   \ the   \ entire   \ system}\$,

I want to ask what does the " maximum  demand   of   the   entire   system" really mean?

Does it mean that The maximum demand of entire system can provide to the user? if yes,we all know that the diversity factor is always \$\ge 1\$, so it means that the "sum individual maximum demands" is always greater or equal than "maximum demand of the entire system".and we will increase the diversity factor to reduce the cost of generation of power.

i think it doesn't make sense ,because that means ,take this for example,three children need 5 dollars for each,but i only have 10 dollars,obviously,i don't have enough money to give every kid 5 dollars,but if we increase the diversity factor,which means i should have the littler money in the begining (\$< 10\$ dollars), or i should give every kid more than 5 dollars so why  will we say it is better to  increase the diversity factor?

Or does it mean that the maximum demand that entire system needed? but why does the system needed? i think the system  should provide something to the user,not the user provide something to  the system.

So what does the " maximum  demand   of   the   entire   system" really mean?

Comment: You are asking about words (factors) that can mean several things to several people. Without a definitive explanation of these words in terms of a text book or on-line authoritative source, this question is unanswerable. Context is required.

Comment: in the power engineering,there is only one Diversity factor  and power factor,so i think if someone understands about them,they can answer my question without context